# Boundary Conditions For Strings?

Tags: string-theory, boundary-conditions

There seems to be two main boundary conditions for Strings. 
1. Neumann Condition: Ends of Strings are free to move up or down. 
2. Dirichlet Condition: Ends of Strings are fixed.

What other boundary conditions are there for Strings? Can anyone name all the boundary conditions we have for strings?

Comment: You can mix-and-match Neumann and Dirichlet (i.e. choose Neumann in half the directions, Dirichlet in the others), but what reason do you have to believe any other boundary conditions are used?

Comment: This appears to be a list-based question.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Uh, yes, the answer is a list of the two things already mentioned in the question. That's not *too broad* - neither are "good answers too long" or are there "too many possible answers". If anything, the question is unclear because there's no reason to think there are other boundary conditions in string theory.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume the "string theory" in this question is about a literal piece of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no other boundary conditions for (open bosonic) strings: The string is fixed in some directions and free in others. There is one important generalization though:

If you impose Dirichlet or Neumann boundary conditions for each coordinate separately, the ends of the strings will always be confined to affine subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$. But in general, the end of an open string can be confined to any $(p+1)$ dimensional submanifold, called a Dp-Brane. Dp-Branes are extremely important objects in string theory, their significance will probably later become clear in your lecture/book.